# what does % 10 mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7

simple question, simple answer. I am mainly asking for code like this:

```
def getSumOfLastDigits(numList):
    return sum (num % 10 for num in numList)
```

Answer (score 6):

Calculate remainder:

```
21 % 10 == 1
 4 % 10 == 4
```

Comment: Don't you mean the remainder :)?

Answer (score 5):

It's a list comprehension to modulus `num` by `10` (get the remainder, or the least significant digit), and then add up the calculated values.

The name of the function (`getSumOfLastDigits()`) is self documenting.

Comment: Actually it's a generator comprehension. Good answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

`%` is the modulo (remainder) operator, e.g. `12 % 7 == 5`.

Answer (score 0):

It is the modulus operator to find the remainder of a number, quite useful in many algorithms